# How to kill a service in android which is runing continuously in back ground

Tags: android, service

In my service I am running an infinite loop how to stop this infinite loop from the activity 
I have tried `stopService()` but its not killing the service. My loop is as follows...

```
while(i>=1)
{
   i++;
}
```

My question is how to stop this infinite loop service .

Comment: call unbindService(serviceConnection);

Answer (score 0):

try to use

stopService(new Intent(ServiceTest.this,ServiceName.class));